# Play Framework as SBT Non-Root Module

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0

I am attempting to develop a Play 2.0 web application alongside a core Java module and other Java clients using SBT. Is it possible to configure this in a way where the Play application is still built properly?

I have developed a small one-off Play 2.0 app before but I have zero experience working with SBT directly. So far I have come up with the following directory structure and `project/Build.scala` file.

```
root/
 |---common/
 |
 |---client1/
 |---client2/
 |
 |---webapp/
 |    |---app/
 |    |---conf/
 |    |---public/
 |
 |---project/
```

.

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
    )

    val common  = Project("hi-common", file("common"))

    val client1 = Project("hi-client1", file("client1")).dependsOn(common)

    val client2 = Project("hi-client2", file("client2")).dependsOn(common)

    val webapp = PlayProject("hi-webapp", appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("webapp"),  mainLang = JAVA).settings(
        // Add your own project settings here      
    ).dependsOn(common)

    val root = Project("hi", file(".")).aggregate(client1, client2, webapp)

}
```

Running `sbt clean package` seems to work appropriately for the `common`, `client1`, and `client2` modules but the `webapp` module is not packaged to a point where I can run `webapp/target/start`.

What can I do to achieve this as a single build with proper output?

Comment: please assign the bounty or half of it will be lost :)

Comment: It won't let me. I believe someone else has to do it when you answer your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that simply running the `package` goal is not enough to generate a start script for you. It will assemble the fully package web application but without a single means of starting it.

My goal was the deployment to Heroku who conveniently provide a plugin which will generate this start script for you. The repository for the plugin's inclusion is added by default with a Play 2.0 web application so all you have to do is modify the commands that you are using for the build to `sbt clean compile stage` and you will find an `start` script in the `webapp/target/` folder.