# Debugging Play 2.2 subproject?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have split Scala/SBT project into several sub-projects. One of the subprojects is Play Framework web application.

After this change I'm struggling to start the application in debug mode. I am able to run it in the following way:

```
$ projects
[info] In file:/my/project/
[info]   * root
[info]     actors
[info]     test
[info]     ui
$ project ui
$ projects
[info] In file:/my/project/
[info]     root
[info]     actors
[info]     test
[info]   * ui
$ run
```

This doesn't open JPDA port for debugging though. What is the way to start a subproject in debug mode?

Comment: How did you *"start the application in debug mode"* before? You can `run` the *ui* project with `ui/run`. Read [Scope axes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#scope-axes).

Comment: When having everything in a single module I was able to run `play debug`. Thank you for the hinting me with the scope axes, it looks like the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Let me know how change the answer so...hint, hint...it gets approved :) We could also work out the question better so it fits your needs.

Comment: Ah, `play debug`. You should be able to do `ui/debug`.

Comment: I have tried that and I'm getting the following errors:  


`play ui/run  
java.lang.RuntimeException: */*:playRunHooks is undefined.  
     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)  
    [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last ui/compile:run for the full output.  
    [error] (ui/compile:run) */*:playRunHooks is undefined.  
    [error] Total time: 92 s, completed May 14, 2014 6:51:54 PM`

Comment: Also the same error is reported when I run sbt directly. `sbt ui/run`

Comment: I guess I have found an answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968952/how-to-create-a-play-2-2-scala-application-as-an-sbt-sub-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968952/how-to-create-a-play-2-2-scala-application-as-an-sbt-sub-project)

Answer (score 0):

There's the section [Debugging](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/PlayConsole) in the official Play documentation that says:

> You can ask Play to start a **JPDA** debug port when starting the console.
>   Use the `activator -jvm-debug <port>` command to do that:
>
> ```
> $ activator -jvm-debug 9999
> ```

With the port open, you should be able to attach to 9999 port and debug away.

[In the older version of Play 2.2](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/PlayConsole), there was `play debug` command that you could use in your case, just scope it to *ui* project.

```
play ui/debug
```

That should give you what you're after.

Comment: It didn't work, but I have found a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968952/how-to-create-a-play-2-2-scala-appl‌​ication-as-an-sbt-sub-project