# Is it possible to run Play2 project from SBT console?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I've created a very simple Play2 project using the TypeSafe activator. However I could not find out how to run it in the SBT console. Is it possible? If so, please tell me how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968952/how-to-create-a-play-2-2-scala-application-as-an-sbt-sub-project might help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not running a multi module project, `sbt run` should be enough.